# PHP фреймворки. Да или нет? Если да, когда это оправдано?

Tags: php

Хоть на этот вопрос и нельзя дать единственно правильного ответа, я очень рассчитываю услышать мнения людей, работающих с **PHP** фреймворками. 
   Долгое время и изучал и писал на **Java/Android**. Сейчас опять возникла необходимость использовать **PHP**. Последний раз я использовал **PHP** версии 4. Сейчас же пытаюсь наверстать упущенное.

Почему назрел этот вопрос? Читая в интернете о **PHP 5+/7**, часто видел упоминания о PHP фреймворках. И это отлично, подумал я. Пока не стал натыкаться на две категории мнений: одни были рады таким возможностям, другие видели в этом проблему.

Естественно все нужно попробовать самому, но я не хочу совершать ошибку многолетней давности, и игнорировать мнения других программистов. Благо голова на плечах есть, и я могу делать выводы для себя из сказанного другими программистами. Где-то не согласиться, а где-то узнать что-то новое или начать думать в том направлении, о котором даже не подозревал.

В любом случае ответ на этот вопрос поможет составить общую картину тем кто в "танке", и повысит шансы на правильное изучение **PHP**.

Comment: Определить, нужен ли фреймворк, очень просто. Если вы планируете использовать больше 10% функциональности фреймворка в своем проекте, то имеет смысл использовать. Но есть нюанс. Посмотрите на эти 10% - вы ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО хотите переложить их на фреймворк, или просто просто добили этот список "до кучи", пытаясь оправдать использование фреймворка?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Использовать или нет фреймворк не имеет отношение к пхп. Это более общий вопрос.

Для начала нужно решить один глобальный вопрос - что такое [фреймворк и чем он отличается от библиотеки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488378/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-framework-%D0%B8-runtime).

А вот теперь можно решать, использовать или нет.

- если проект маленький-маленький, то фреймворки точно не нужны.
- если планируется написать проект-велосипед (например, что бы потренироваться в каких то фичах), то тут очевидно, что не нужно использовать фреймворк или как минимум не использовать фреймворк для велосипедных функций.
- если нужно сделать проект быстро, то лучше потратить немного время, найти фреймворк, который решает задачи проекта и использовать его. Иначе все равно придется эти функции/классы написать, а это может занять много лишнего времени. И хорошим решением будет взять человека, который знает найденный фреймворк.
- если планируется делать большой проект, то также есть смысл использовать фреймворк, но потом в будущем вполне возможно, что он  будет полностью переписан/выпелен.

Когда точно не стоит использовать фреймворк:

- если Вы делаете домашнее задание в вузе и Ваш преподаватель не знает/не любит фреймворки/библиотеки.
- если Вы делаете ТЗ и там явно об этом сказано.
- если Вы понимаете, что в проекте нужен ещё один (и ещё один) фреймворк. В этом случае либо был неверно выбран начальный фреймворк, либо Вы не до конца рабобрались в начальном.
- если фреймворк вышел вчера, а кол-во вопросов-ответов на SO по нему в районе нуля.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд за счет использования фреймворков упрощается сопровождение кода, единый подход к архитектуре и стилю программирования, плюс своевременные исправления безопасности, плюс своевременная оптимизация и тп. Ну и классического программирования никто не отменял без этих знаний не один фремворк вам не поможет (вот такие люди как раз и являются недовольными). Так что вы ничего не потеряете, а только приобретете.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идёт о проектах которые могут/должны поддерживаться сторонними разработчиками - лучше пользоваться фреймворками, будет ниже порог входа. Для мелких обработчиков/API этот подход конечно избыточен. В общем всё зависит от задачи. Но знать хотя бы один из актуальных фреймворков на уровне выше среднего - надо обязательно.

Answer (score 0):

Во фреймворках продуманы уже многие вещи, которые можно брать из коробки и пользоваться ими. Например авторизация, роутинг, работа с бд, валидация форм и так далее. Если Вы начнете делать что то из этого сами, во первых уйдет много времени, во вторых можете допустить ошибки. А во фреймворке просто берете вызываете нужный метод и все.

Но из за своей универсальности, они более громоздки. Если вам нужно делать рекламный одностраничник, тогда фреймворк не нужен. Если предполагается разрабатывать серьезный сайт, то при использовании фреймворка приложение будет писаться быстрее и с его ростом, легче будет управлять написанным кодом.